# group the similar index value and reindexing each group by new index pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have df with the values and similar index like

```
>>> df
idx  a  b
0  15  15
0  15  15
0  15  15
1  20  20
1  20  20
1  20  20
1  20  20
1  20  20
```

while I want to assign each group separate index like result below. How can I get this in pandas

group by

```
>>
idx  a  b
0  15  15
1  15  15
2  15  15
0  20  20
1  20  20
2  20  20
3  20  20
4  20  20
```

Comment: `df.index = df.groupby(df.index).cumcount()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [cumcount](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html)

```
>>> df['idx'] = df.groupby('idx').cumcount()
>>> df
   idx   a   b
0    0  15  15
1    1  15  15
2    2  15  15
3    0  20  20
4    1  20  20
5    2  20  20
6    3  20  20
7    4  20  20
```